# Akka :: dispatcher [%name%] not configured, using default-dispatcher

Tags: configuration, akka, dispatcher

I created the followind application.conf:

```
akka {

    actor {

        prio-dispatcher {
            type = "Dispatcher"
            mailbox-type = "my.package.PrioritizedMailbox"
        }

    }

}
```

when dumping configuration with

```
actorSystem = ActorSystem.create()
println(actorSystem.settings)
```

I'm getting the output:

```
        # application.conf: 5
        "prio-dispatcher" : {
            # application.conf: 7
            "mailbox-type" : "my.package.PrioritizedMailbox",
            # application.conf: 6
            "type" : "Dispatcher"
        },
```

and later on

```
[WARN] [08/30/2012 22:44:54.362] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [Dispatchers] Dispatcher [prio-dispatcher] not configured, using default-dispatcher
```

What am I missing here?

**UPD** Found the solution [here](http://groups.google.com/group/akka-user/browse_thread/thread/678f2ae1c068e0fa), had to use the name "akka.actor.prio-dispatcher"

Comment: Please add an answer to your question and self-accept it.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The configuration above dictates that name of mailbox is **akka.actor.prio-dispatcher**

Description of the problem: http://groups.google.com/group/akka-user/browse_thread/thread/678f2ae1c068e0fa

Comment: awesome! How can this still not be explained in the doc, I've been scratching my head for a while now.