# Unable to provision because of "No implementation for controllers.MyExecutionContext was bound"

Tags: scala, playframework, guice

I'm trying to follow the instructions to create a Play Framework async controller. So far my code is little more than a [cut & paste from the Play documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaAsync):

```
package controllers

import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import com.google.inject.Inject
import play.api.libs.concurrent.CustomExecutionContext
import play.api.mvc.{AbstractController, ControllerComponents}
import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, Future}
trait MyExecutionContext extends ExecutionContext

class MyExecutionContextImpl @Inject()(system: ActorSystem)
  extends CustomExecutionContext(system, "my.executor") with MyExecutionContext

class FooController @Inject() (myExecutionContext: MyExecutionContext, cc:ControllerComponents) extends AbstractController(cc) {
  def foo = Action.async(
    Future {
      // Call some blocking API
      Ok("result of blocking call")
    }(myExecutionContext)

  )
}
```

When I try to run this new controller, I get the following error:

ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

```
1) No implementation for controllers.MyExecutionContext was bound.
  while locating controllers.MyExecutionContext
    for the 1st parameter of controllers.FooController.<init>(FooController.scala:14)
  while locating controllers.FooController
    for the 4th parameter of router.Routes.<init>(Routes.scala:33)
  while locating router.Routes
  while locating play.api.inject.RoutesProvider
```

Can anybody explain what might be going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception indicates that you have not bound the implementation (`MyExecutionContext`) to the trait (`MyExecutionContextImpl`) in your Module.

Try this:

```
class Module extends AbstractModule {

  override def configure(): Unit = {
    bind(classOf[MyExecutionContext])
      .to(classOf[MyExecutionContextImpl])

  }
}
```

However I never used your approach. I use only the default Execution Context like:

```
class FooController @Inject()()(implicit val ec: ExecutionContext)
```

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer does not work. Try instead using [@ImplementedBy](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/ScalaDependencyInjection#Binding-annotations)
(source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53162884/4965515)

In addition you will need to configure your executor in conf/application.conf. For instance try adding:

```
my.executor {
  type = Dispatcher
  executor = "thread-pool-executor"
  thread-pool-executor {
    core-pool-size-factor = 10.0
    core-pool-size-max = 10
  }
}
```

(source https://stackoverflow.com/a/46013937/4965515)