# How do make a `CustomExecutionContext` available for dependency injection in a Play 2.6 controller?

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, playframework

I'm following along with [Play 2.6's Scala documentation and sample code for creating non-blocking actions](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaAsync#Creating-non-blocking-actions), and am running into some runtime issues. I have created a new Play application using the [Scala template](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/NewApplication#Scala-template) (`sbt new playframework/play-scala-seed.g8`).

The code that the Play documentation suggests should work in a new controller is (this code is taken verbatim from the Play documentation page, with some extra imports from me):

```
// some imports added by me to get the code to compile
import javax.inject.Inject
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext
import scala.concurrent.Future

import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import play.api.libs.concurrent.CustomExecutionContext
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.mvc.ControllerComponents
// end imports added by me

import play.api.libs.concurrent.CustomExecutionContext

trait MyExecutionContext extends ExecutionContext

class MyExecutionContextImpl @Inject()(system: ActorSystem)
  extends CustomExecutionContext(system, "my.executor") with MyExecutionContext

class HomeController @Inject()(myExecutionContext: MyExecutionContext, val controllerComponents: ControllerComponents) extends BaseController {
  def index = Action.async {
    Future {
      // Call some blocking API
      Ok("result of blocking call")
    }(myExecutionContext)
  }
}
```

Then, according to the [documentation for using other thread pools](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ThreadPools#Using-other-thread-pools), I've defined the `my.executor` thread pool in the `application.conf` file of my application:

```
my.executor {
  fork-join-executor {
    parallelism-factor = 20.0
    parallelism-max = 200
  }
}
```

I should note that I do **not** want to use the default execution context as I want to prepare for running futures in a separate context that may be used for a limited resource like a database connection pool.

All of this compiles just fine with `sbt compile`. However, when I run this with `sbt run` and access my app in a web browser, I get this error:

> CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:
>
> 1) No implementation for controllers.MyExecutionContext was bound.
>     while locating controllers.MyExecutionContext
>       for the 1st parameter of controllers.NewController.(NewController.scala:17)
>     while locating controllers.NewController
>       for the 2nd parameter of router.Routes.(Routes.scala:29)
>     at play.api.inject.RoutesProvider$.bindingsFromConfiguration(BuiltinModule.scala:121):
>   Binding(class router.Routes to self) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$1)

I've used Play 2.3 in the past, and know that dependency injection works when you define an instance of an object (via `@Singleton` or in a module); however, [Play 2.6's documentation on DI](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaDependencyInjection#Declaring-runtime-DI-dependencies) indicates that "Guice is able to automatically instantiate any class with an @Inject on its constructor without having to explicitly bind it. This feature is called just in time bindings is described in more detail in the Guice documentation."

My question is: what specific lines of code or configuration do I need to add to Play's own sample to make this work, and why?

Comment: There should be a `Modules` file somewhere in your project that can allow you rto bind specific implementations.

Answer (score 2):

I found one possible solution when reading further in the [Binding Annotations](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaDependencyInjection#Binding-annotations) section of the Scala Dependency Injection documentation page. In particular, it states:

> The simplest way to bind an implementation to an interface is to use the Guice @ImplementedBy annotation.

So, by adding that to the my `MyExecutionContext` `trait`, like so:

```
import com.google.inject.ImplementedBy

@ImplementedBy(classOf[MyExecutionContextImpl])
trait MyExecutionContext extends ExecutionContext
```

an instance of the `MyExecutionContextImpl` is instantiated and properly injected into the controller.

Too bad that this `@ImplementedBy` annotation isn't listed in the sample code for the [non-blocking action](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaAsync#Creating-non-blocking-actions) documentation!